# SFTP client for OS X for updating external website

Tags: software-recommendation, data-transfer, macos, sftp

I do update a website for my company, and for that I currently have the following workflow:

1. Make a local mirror of the external website
2. Update files in the local mirror that is going to be updated on the external site
3. Verify that the files that are going to be uploaded to the external site is correct
4. Upload files using SFTP

Currently I use FileZilla to upload files. To verify that the update is correct, and that nothing more has accidentally changed, I would like to see the changes between the external and the local before performing the upload.

To perform the verification I need to download the file from the external site and perform a diff on the files.

My first thought was that there must be a easier way to do this, and that it might be that there are SFTP clients that integrate this "under the hood".

Are there any SFTP clients for OS X that let you compare and see the differences between a local file and the file on the server before doing an upload.

Comment: Since you can do sftp I assume you can ssh, would you consider using rsync over it?

Comment: Could I use rsync to make a simulated (nothing is changed externally) diff before I choose to perform the transfer?

Comment: Great edit and hopefully it will be re-opened. Why not use git instead as it sounds like it would eliminate all of the problems from the source? FTP deployment can be risky, often with little recourse if something does go wrong also.

Comment: rsync has --dry-run flag which will report actions to be taken without actually performing it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Transmit from Panic](https://panic.com/transmit/). It doesn't allow an actual file to file content comparison like a diff, but you can do a simulated sync to see which files will be replaced or deleted.

If you drag one file from window to window it asks you to verify and gives you the information on both files regarding modification dates and times.

You can try it before you buy it. I would think any good FTP client should do a simulated transfer.